# Redirecting website to subdirectory, while retaining index.php file in parent directory to allow access to site archive

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web-hosting

I have two versions of a website: the old version uses wordpress for the front end, pages, display etc, whereas the new version does not.

The old site is in the public_html/ folder and is launched from the index.php wordpress file

The new site is in a subdirectory (let's call it public_html/newsite/) and it has its own index.php file.

I'd like the new site to display by default, but have the option of linking back to the old site as an archive.

I have tried editing the .htaccess directory index to prioritize index.html over index.php, and created a new index.html file in the main public_html/ folder which redirects to the new site subdirectory using a simple meta refresh tag.

This works to redirect the site, but even if I explicitly link back to the index.php file in old site parent directory, it loads the index.html file instead

I cannot change the name of the parent directory (old site) index.php because it messes up the wordpress architecture.

Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your newsite in the subdirectory entirely _static_? ie. Serving static `.html` files?

Comment: No the new site is php with dynamic includes - content will continue to be added using the existing wordpress architecture from the old site as they want an easy non-technical way to continue to update the new site

Comment: In that case (assuming `/newsite/` is not visible in the URL) how do you differentiate between WordPress URLs and URLs that should be routed through the "newsite"?

Comment: The behaviour I'd like to have is: if you go to mainurl.com, the directoryindex loads the html file (redirect.html) which redirects to mainurl.com/newsite/ - and on visiting the newsite there is a link which says 'old site' which links back to mainsite.com/index.php

Comment: /newsite/ is visible in the redirected url

Comment: Please show us what you actually did, instead of giving us just an ambiguous verbal description of it. Show us what your .htaccess contains, exactly, and what _"explicitly link back to the index.php file in old site parent directory"_ really looks like.